# Problems with incrementing location of widget creation when function is called

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I am trying to make this function create a label and 2 buttons respectively, and each time this function is called, 3the widgets will be created on the next row(directly under the previous 3 widgets).

Howver, I am not sure why the items keep being created on the same row (effectively overlapping over the same one when the function is called) despite the counter being incremented.

```
    def fetch_quick(self, entries):
    for entry in entries:
        text = entry[1].get()
        print(text)

        exec("app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + "= tk.Frame(app._master, bg='white')")
        exec("app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ".grid(row=" + str(self._qqq+6) + ")")

        exec("self.queue_entry_quick" + str(self._qqq) + " = Label(app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ", text='1    '+text +'                 0                              a few seconds ago')")
        exec("self.queue_entry_quick" + str(self._qqq) + ".grid(row=" + str(self._qqq) + ")")

        exec("self._Button" + str(self._qqq) + " = Button(app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ", text = self._qqq, width = 2, command=app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ".destroy, bg='red')")
        exec("self._Buttonb" + str(self._qqq) + " = Button(app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ", text = self._qqq, width = 2, command=app._framea" + str(self._qqq+7) + ".destroy, bg='green')")



        exec("self._Button" + str(self._qqq) + ".grid(row=" + str(self._qqq) + ", column=1)")
        exec("self._Button" + str(self._qqq) + ".bind('<Button-1>',self.call)")
        exec("self._Buttonb" + str(self._qqq) + ".grid(row=" + str(self._qqq) + ", column=2)")
        exec("self._Buttonb" + str(self._qqq) + ".bind('<Button-1>',self.call)")
        abcd.append(text)  
        self._qqq += 1
        print(self._qqq)
```

I think it might be the issue of the widgets' creation location(on the grid) being pre-set to row 0 for all of the widgets and thus it will not update self._qqq for each time the function is called. If this is the case, I am still unsure of what to do about it

Comment: Isn't it just overwriting the frame each loop? `app._frame7 = tk.Frame(app._master, bg="white")`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I realised I didnt think through what I was doing, but I fixed it now thanks to what you said

Comment: I've done it a few times, just kind of forget what the loop is doing sometimes.

Comment: It's a _very_ bad idea to use `exec` to create variable names. It renders your code almost completely unreadable. Store your widgets in a dictionary instead. Also, the indentation of your code is a bit off and needs to be fixed.